# Stop re-installing same deb file using dpkg -i

Tags: deb

I have created a .deb file and it is working fine after installing. But when I am going to re-install the same deb file then previous version is uninstalled and then new deb file is installed (using dpkg -i deb file). How can I restrict installation if previous version is already installed? I have a spec file for deb file specification. and I am using rpm build to create a deb file.

**script.spec**

```
%define name        StudentData 
%define release     2.4
%define version     Linux

Summary:        StudentData
License:        MCS
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source0:        StudentData.tar.gz

Group:          Applications/System
Requires:       jdk >= 8

BuildRoot: %{$RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/%{name}-%{version}

%description
StudentData

%prep
%setup -n StudentData

%build

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/StudentData/"
install -m 755 %{SOURCE0} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/StudentData/
cp -R * "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/StudentData/"
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/"
ln -sf /usr/local/StudentData/StudentData $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/
ln -sf /usr/local/StudentData/TMCAutoUpdate $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/

%post
chmod 777 -R /usr/local/StudentData/

ln -s /usr/local/StudentData/StudentDataConfiguration.desktop  ~/Desktop/StudentDataConfiguration.desktop
echo 'StudentData installed on "/usr/local/StudentData"' > /dev/stderr

%preun

rm -rf ~/Desktop/StudentDataConfiguration.desktop

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
/usr/local/StudentData/
/usr/local/bin/
%exclude /usr/local/StudentData/*.tar.gz
%doc
```

**Command  to build deb file**

```
rpmbuild -ba <path to spec file>

alien --scripts -v /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/<name>.rpm
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? You can use `apt install` instead of `dpkg -i`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
In both the cases I have to restrict installation and also restrict after double click install

Comment: Why would you "restrict" it. Nothing wrong will happen if the same version is installed.

Comment: This is the specification of our project